# Howto record audio output on my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, recording, voice

How am I able to record the output on my Mac meanwhile I am listening it with earplug? i.e. listen something in browser in youtube and I want to record it as well?

Answer (score 1):

Need two thing to be able to listen music and same time record it:

1. [Download / Install Soundflower](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/25/record-system-audio-mac-os-x-soundflower/)
2. Change Audio Midi Setup:

If you open OSX's 'Audio Midi Setup' program then from the Window menu choose 'show audio window', you can click the + button in the bottom left corner & create a multi-output device. Then you just check the boxes for both soundflower and the built in output and Bob's your uncle - you can hear it as well as record it.